# What does it mean to "Decide to which group $G$ is isomorphic" for a given group $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a homework question which is

> Decide to which group $(\mathbb{Z}_n^*,\,\cdot\,)$ is isomorphic (classification of finite abelian groups), for
>     (i) $n = 9$,
>     (ii) $n = 15$.

But I don't understand what it means. Should I decide whether $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$ is isomorphic or I need to do something else?

Comment: It means that there is some label or name or symbolic representation for the group's isomorphism class that is considered standard for the context of the problem, and you must decide what it is. Presumably you can/should just write their decompositions as direct sums of cyclic groups (per classification of finite abelian groups).

Comment: Which group (in your notes/book) is Z*9 isomorphic to? Which group is Z*15 isomorphic to? (I'm not certain what's going on - though I can make a good guess - but this is what your question is asking you. If you need more help, you'll have to give more context!)

Comment: I think it's reasonable to believe the OP wrote in the astericks because these are the multiplicative group of units mod $n$.

Comment: I think Z*n means the set of non zero elements in Zn which are not zero divisors with respect to multiplication.

Comment: "Should I decide whether $\mathbb Z_9^*$ and $\mathbb Z_{15}^*$ is isomorphic"?! Isomorphic *to what*? If I have to take what you've written at face value, I'm forced to conclude that you just don't understand what the word 'isomorphic' means and how it's used in a sentence. Similarly to the student that when asked "[...] are the groups $G$ and $H$ as defined above isomorphic?" answers "$G$ is, but $H$ isn't".

Comment: @kahen: I think that English may not be the OP's first language, and this question could definitely be made clearer; I would have stated the question as: *Decide which group of the form*
$$\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{a_1}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p_k^{a_k}\mathbb{Z}$$
*$G$ is isomorphic to, for $G=\mathbb{Z}_9^*$ and for $G=\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$* (the allusion to the classification of finite abelian groups is too indirect in the original question, the "to" and "which" should be separated, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you mean $\mathbb Z_n^*$.

Your question means that for

$(i)$ Find the group that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_9^*$: you'll want to determine how to represent it as the decomposition into the direct product of cyclic groups (one or more factors): Express this isomorphism as the decomposition.

$(ii)$ Find the group that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{15}^*$. Again, use decomposition to express this as the direct product of cyclic groups, and express this isomorphism as its decomposition.

For any group denoted by $\mathbb Z_n^*,\,$ alternatively denoted by $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, \cdot),\,$ there are $\phi(n)$ elements in this group, the elements being those integers (each representing a congruence class) strictly between $0$ and $n$ and which are coprime to $n$. $\;\phi(n) = n − 1\,$ if and only if $n$ is itself a prime. Once you determine the order of each group, decomposition into the direct product of cyclic products of the same order should easily fall out. (If you have further questions, feel free to comment below.)

Comment: Deserves a thumbs up! +1

Comment: I cannot help but think that giving the answer away like this spoils the OPs enjoyment of the question. The eureka! moment has been stolen...

Comment: @user1729 The question asked was about the point (meaning) of the question, not about how to answer it. I simply clarified the question, relating it to what the user posted: who already knew that it was about its relation to finitely generated abelian groups. So I don't know what I "gave away": I certainly didn't "give away" the order of either group, nor its decomposition, so the OP can still "enjoy" the eureka! (Note, if you view the revision/edit history, you can see the OP didn't know how to interpret the question as it was phrased.)

Comment: @AmWhy Eureka moments are not always at the end - I have alway thought that the eureka moment here is when you realise that $\varphi(n)$ is what you are after.

Comment: Holy $\mathbb Z^{*}$